# $q.when(string) in observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a function in angular 2 project that should returns a token. Token might exists in `localStorage` or fetched from server. Since I want the function caller to get the same result type I return `Observable.from(localStorage.getItem("token"))`, if token does exist in `localStorage`.

The problem is that `Observable.from(someString)` yields each character  seperatly. Is there a way to use Observable like `$q.when` in angularjs?

Comment: `Observable.of(someString)`

Comment: `Observable.of(localStorage.getItem("token"))`

Comment: Thanks - worked great :-)

Comment: You can check my medium article that gives you mapping between $q and rxjs. "$Q map to RxJS" https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova/q-map-to-rxjs-981936a2b22d